# How to stop a controller action which is running in background in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code follows MVC structure, or more specifically I am using Codeigniter. I want to run something in the background (infinite loop). But I want to stop it at some point. How to do it?

I have tried passing a stop signal to the running action but not working

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller 
{   
    public $stop = false;

    public function start()
    {
        ignore_user_abort(); 
        set_time_limit(0);
        do{
            ....//do something, such as trading bitcoins
        }while(! $this->stop); 
    }

    public function stop()
    {
        $this->stop = true;
    }

}
```

So what I want to do is first start the running by typing "mydomain.com/my_controller/start" on the browser, and then stop it by typing "mydomain.com/my_controller/stop" on the browser. But the stop action does not return, and it just keeps waiting. Could anyone tell me how to stop the background running action? I cannot stop it simply by killing PID because I am using shared web hosting.

The reason why I am  doing this is because I want to write code for automatic bitcoin trading, i.e., my application will keep running 7 X 24 in the background, getting market information, analyzing the data and sending commands for trading to platforms. So I need to control the stopping when necessary.

Comment: sounds like you want a cron job, what you are describing is not an acceptable practice.

Comment: @Alex no necessarily a cron job. I just want to start a job (which repeatedly does something) in the background, and I want to be able to control the stopping. what is an acceptable practice? thanks

Comment: a cron job, as well as something that doesn't continually run and bog down your server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with running CLI commands and your shared hosting provider allows you to have shell access to your account, you could write a handler to [run via a CLI command](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html). CodeIgniter makes this cleverly simple. Once you've got it working, you can type the CLI command followed by an ampersand (eg, `php -f index.php controller_name route_name &` and the process will run in the process until killed with the `kill` command.

Beware, however, that an infinite loop can quickly cause out-of-control CPU and/or RAM usage on your system, and your shared hosting provider won't be very happy with you if they detect that. I suggest you use [sleep()](https://php.net/sleep) to pause for the maximally acceptable amount of time between executions of the loop of your code. Also, go over your code carefully and make sure you're not increasing memory usage on each loop of your code by doing something like endlessly appending to an array or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Garret for the suggestions. I have SSH access to the server, and I have basic knowledge of Shell. Could you give me more details, say, what is the shell command for executing "start‘ as in the above My_controller example? Is it "php -f index.php my_controller start"? and if I want to pass parameters do I just need to append "& params"? Thank you very much!

Comment: This works but it seems that I have to leave the shell window open. Once I close the shell terminal, the controller/action will stop running. This isn't what I want. I want to launch it and leave it unattended until I want to stop it.  My application is for automatic bitcoin trading, i.e., my application will keep running 7 X 24 in the background: getting market information, analyzing the data and sending commands for trading to platforms. So I don't want to keep a shell terminal open on my end and  I need to control the stopping when necessary. I'd appreciate if you can come up with something

Comment: @TaoHu Yes, you'd do `php -f index.php my_controller start`. Anything after that would be passed as parameters to the function, so if the `start` method took two params, you could do `php -f index.php my_controller start firstParamVal secondParamVal`. As for having to leave the shell window open, sorry, didn't consider that, but it sounds like the `nohup` approach from the other answer is working for you.